# Update C# no funciona

Tags: c#

Hola amaigos estoy tratando de hace un update con **C#** desde **VS**, pero no lo consigo y no sé si le estoy pasando mal algo o si no puede ejecutar un query directamente como yo pretendo agradecería su ayuda. :D

```
[WebMethod]
public JsonResult UpDateEnEspera(string req_id) {


  string cs = "Data Source=DMX87025;Initial Catalog=DB_PCC;Integrated Security=True";


  using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cs)) {
    using(SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
      command.CommandText = "UPDATE [DB_PCC].[dbo].[Requests]  SET [status] = 1  WHERE [id] = " + req_id;

      connection.Open();

      command.ExecuteNonQuery();

      connection.Close();
    }

  }

  return Json(new {
    success = true, message = "Status cambiado"
  }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por aquí les dejo el error completo

```css
Server Error in '/' Application. Incorrect syntax near '='. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '='. Source Error : Line 108: command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("reqId", req_id));
Line 109 : Line 110: connection.Open();
Line 111 : Line 112: command.ExecuteNonQuery();
Source File: D: \PCotiza - compras_casifinal\ PCotiza - compras\ Controllers\ RequestController.cs Line: 110 Stack Trace : [SqlException(0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near '='.] System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action `1 wrapCloseInAction)+2440274 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action` 1 wrapCloseInAction)+5765240 System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)+285 System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean & dataReady)+4169 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)+948 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource `1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)+286 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()+286 PCotiza_compras.Controllers.RequestController.UpDateEnEspera(String req_id) in D:\PCotiza-compras_casifinal\PCotiza-compras\Controllers\RequestController.cs:110 lambda_method(Closure, ControllerBase, Object[])+103 System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)+14 System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary` 2 parameters)+157 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary `2 parameters)+27 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)+22 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult` 2. CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)+29 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase `1.End()+49 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)+32 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()+50 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()+228 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)+10 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult` 1. CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)+10 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase `1.End()+49 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)+34 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()+26 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)+100 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult` 1. CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)+10 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase `1.End()+49 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)+27 System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)+13 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid` 1. CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)+29 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase `1.End()+49 System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)+36 System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller)+12 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid` 1. CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)+22 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase `1.End()+49 System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)+26 System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)+10 System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)+21 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid` 1. CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)+29 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase `1.End()+49 System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)+28 System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)+9 System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()+9987265 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)+155
```

```js
Server Error in '/'
Application.
Incorrect syntax near '='.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.Please review the stack trace
for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '='.

Source Error:


  Line 108: command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("reqId", req_id));
Line 109:
  Line 110: connection.Open();
Line 111:
  Line 112: command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Source File: D: \PCotiza - compras_casifinal\ PCotiza - compras\ Controllers\ RequestController.cs Line: 110

Stack Trace:


  [SqlException(0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near '='.]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action `1 wrapCloseInAction) +2440274
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`
  1 wrapCloseInAction) + 5765240
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) + 285
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean & dataReady) + 4169
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) + 948
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource `1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) +286
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +286
   PCotiza_compras.Controllers.RequestController.UpDateEnEspera(String req_id) in D:\PCotiza-compras_casifinal\PCotiza-compras\Controllers\RequestController.cs:110
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +103
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`
  2 parameters) + 157
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary `2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`
    2. CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) + 29 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase `1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`
    1. CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) + 10 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase `1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`
    1. CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) + 10 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase `1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`
    1. CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) + 29 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase `1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`
    1. CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) + 22 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase `1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`
    1. CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) + 29 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase `1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9987265
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: Seguramente llevas vacío en la variable `req_id`, por eso el error. Como sugerencia, tu código es susceptible a [Inyección SQL](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx), nunca debes concatenar variables, se deben armar las consultas por medio de parámetros.

Comment: Voy a resaltar lo que todos ya dijeron.. porque nunca estas mostrando como queda el query y las respuestas que te dieron no tienen nada que ver con el problema. EL QUERY ESTA MAL. Eso dice el error. req_id no viene como vos pensas que viene, o directamente no viene. De alguna forma tenes que hacer un debug, mostrar como esta quedando el query y vas a ver que esta mal formado.

Answer (score 1):

No deberías concatenar strings cuando utilizas SQL. En cambio, siempre utiliza parámetros para evitar inyecciones de SQL:

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cs))  
{
    using(SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand()) 
    {
        command.CommandText = "UPDATE [DB_PCC].[dbo].[Requests] SET [status] = 1 WHERE [id] = @reqId";
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("reqId", reqId));

        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Además, si utilizas `using`, no es necesario llamar explícitamente a `connection.Close()` ya que el `Dispose()` lo llama.

Comment: Hola les aseguro que he seguido este código y me tira el mismo error donde die haber un error cerca del " = " y en este caso "linea 110  connection.Open(); " , hay algo con lo que pueda separar valores en sql ??

Comment: @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim estas seguro que `req_id` no es nulo y tampoco `string.Empty`?

Comment: pues si fuese null o vacio me tiraría el error por ahí , no crees? ya he estado por ahí XD, hasta donde se si les estoy pasando algo

Comment: Puede ser, puedes copiar el error exacto y completo?

Comment: Listo . muchas grácias :)

Answer (score 0):

Es mejor hacer lo que te indica Camilo con parametros, pero si lo haces concatenado string, te falta añadir las comillas simples,
te quedaria asi:

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE [DB_PCC].[dbo].[Requests]  SET [status] = 1  WHERE [id] = '" + req_id + "'";
```

Comment: tambien traté mandando el query así ...

Comment: Para que le pongas comillas simples es necesario saber si la columna `[id]` es de tipo `VARCHAR`, no obstante, `req_id` puede ser de igual forma un número que se introduce y se obtiene en un `string`